# Best Strategy to Unit Test Applications Calling java.util.Random

Tags: java, unit-testing

My Java application involves generating many random numbers at various places.  I am very careful to make sure my application retrieves the java.util.Random object from a factory class so that I am able to replace it with a mock object that generates a constant during unit test. But still that is not a satisfactory unit test strategy since some of the branches can only be reached if the sequence of random numbers generated is of certain pattern.

How should we unit test when java.util.Random is involved but we want to control how numbers are returned in a deterministic way?  It is still not very satisfactory to hard code a specific sequence of random numbers to return in my Mock java.util.Random as this also hard code the calling sequence in the unit test which is very likely to change if I add another call to retrieve a random number in some unrelated method in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Random(long seed)` object like this.
By giving it the same seed every time, it should give back the same random numbers

Comment: Making Random.nextInt() to return the same set of numbers is not the major issue (as suggested by you).  For the purpose of unit testing, I need to CONTROL what numbers are returned so that I can increase the coverage. But at the same tiem I dont want to hardcode how many times my application will issue call to retrieve a random number.

Comment: This ensures a predictable behaviour, but still makes it hard to ensure that certain code paths are covered. Maybe mocks with hard coded sequences are still better suited for that.

Comment: If you need full control over the numbers returned, you have to hardcode them, I'm sorry. Best thing you could probably do is to hardcode them in an array and count the calls to return the correct arrayentry

Comment: The problem is hardcoding them in an array is a fragile way. For example, if later somebody add an extra call to get a random number, the hardcoded sequence will no long works and many working unit tests will fail mysteriously.  This is worse than no test.

Comment: Yeah, of course... but I don't think there is a better way. If you find one, please let me know!

Comment: In addition to hardcoded sequences, you could also use model based testing (e.g. ModelJUnit). This approach automatically creates test cases by randomly calling your code and comparing the behaviour of the system under test with a predefined "behaviour model".

Comment: Well, if you have to rely on the calling order for your test, every change in that order will break everything

Answer (score 1):

You can look into a mocking framework like JMockit. JMockit is one of the few that supports mocking actual implemtations of classes like Random. With the mocked instance you can return a value for which you want to run your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fake implementing your expected "random pattern" instead of a mock.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the suggestion to "guess" how the various random values will evolve during your program's execution. While it is indeed true that if you have a single function in a loop calling `Random.next()` several times in a row it is difficult to avoid having to consider the sequence of generated random numbers, you should try to minimize that as much as possible.

The easiest way to avoid it is to make sure you can at any time pass the Random class instance yourself to the different classes / methods. Avoid passing around the Random instance class from the root of your instances' graph. It then gets way easier to reach and test consistently any module you desire.